# partial view c# using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying to return from controller partial view using ajax
while debugging I see that the correct data is sent to the controller
but when the controller finished to do what his need
he moved automaticaly to function `Dispose` instead to return the partial view

The code in the controller is:

```
    public PartialViewResult SearchPosts(string keyword)
    {
        var data = db.Posts.Where(f => f.Title.Contains(keyword) || f.Author.Contains(keyword)).ToList();
        return PartialView("_SearchPostsPArtial", data);
    }
```

and partial code from the View is:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buttonSearch').click(function () {
            var keyword = $('#searchAjax').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchPosts", "Posts")',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { keyword: keyword },
                dataType: 'html'
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#result').html(result);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                console.debug(status);
            })
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have here some statements and some code but you don't ask a question. What exactly is your question? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Normal scenario on using ajax is return data in global string formats (specially in j-son format), Why you want to use partial-view returned action for that? If you need this partial view anyway I suggest write another action to response to your ajax call and if your action does many code you could split it to tow method and call the main section in partial-view and ajax-response actions, pseudo code could be like this:

```
private GetData([parameters...])
{
  ...
  code to get proper data
  ...
}
public PartialViewResult SearchPosts(string keyword)
{
  [DataType] data = GetData([variables...]);
  return PartialView("_SearchPostsPArtial", data);
}

public JsonResult SearchPosts(string keyword)
{
  [DataType] data = GetData([variables...]);
  return Json(data);
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: thnaks for the fast response

Comment: thaks for the fast reponse ,i have view that produced posts i need the search posts per author name,or title. the first load of the view shows all posts but after search i need to produce just the posts that contain the word that i searched , so i tought to return from controller a partial view and to load it instead some div with id i saw in guids this way but its work to me while debbuging i saw that the controller really return the right data but when he arrived to return partial view he steel running and moved to dispose function instead to return that partial view

Comment: Your welcome, Unfortunately can't understand new description, can you please clarify more?

Comment: its okay i fixed that i needed only to create the _PartialView page in the view many thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome again, I glad to hear that :)